# How can I calculate the required sample size for Latent Growth Curve Modelling?

Tags: statistical-power, structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable, growth-model

I am looking to calculate what sample size I would need for my study by running an a priori power analysis.

Is there any way (e.g an R package) I can calculate the required sample size required for latent growth curve modelling?

Answer (score 10):

This is a little bit of a guess about what you want to do.

With the exception of simple/classic statistical tests and models (e.g. 1-way ANOVA, t-test, proportion test, general linear model, etc.), almost all power calculations are based on simulations of the proposed model.

People who do latent growth curve modeling in R seem to use the `lavaan` package (e.g. see [here](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/seminars/lgm/#s1h)).

The `semPower` package, specifically [here](https://moshagen.github.io/semPower/#powerLGCM) discusses how to do simulation-based power analysis with `semPower.powerLGCM()`.

Answer (score 4):

> almost all power calculations are based on simulations of the proposed model

Indeed, simulation is currently necessary for anything but the ideal case.  But if you simulate normally distributed, completely observed data, then an analytical power method will be more precise with less computational demand:

- LRT: https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02294150
- Tests using RMSEA's CI: https://doi.org/10.1037/1082-989X.1.2.130 and https://doi.org/10.1037/1082-989X.11.1.19

Both are implemented in the [`semTools`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=semTools) package. After loading the package, open the `?semTools` help page to find a list of functions in the Power Analysis section.

This [tutorial](https://doi.org/10.3758/s13428-020-01479-0) describes both and has an associated [Shiny app](https://sjak.shinyapps.io/power4SEM/) implementing both.

If you do need to simulate nonnormal (including ordinal) data or incomplete data, the [`simsem`](https://simsem.org/) package also has a lot of useful features (particularly for different missing-data mechanisms). Like [Ben](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/2126/ben-bolker)'s suggestion, these tools all utilize the R package [`lavaan`](https://lavaan.ugent.be/), although the source material for analytical methods does not presuppose any particular software.